# Сделать гиперссылку из каждого элемента List

Tags: python, list, aiogram, href

Использую aiogram и функцию hlinks.
Есть два списка одинаковой длины
nameList = [ ] # тут имена
urlList = [ ]  # тут ссылки

Требуется через функцию hlinks сделать гиперссылки для каждого элемента nameList используя ссылку urlList
должно получится так:

```
<a href="http://url1.ru">name1</a>
<a href="http://url2.ru">name2</a> и тд
```

hlinks принимает 2 параметра str: hlinks('str',url)

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

вобщем решил проблему, если у кого то будет более элегантное решение welcome )

```
cList = list(zip(nameList, urlList))
    for x in cList:
        sS = hlink(x[0], x[1])
        print(sS)
```